# How to know which functions the package includes?

Tags: c++, c, package

For example, I have `#include <string.h>`. How to know which functions the `string.h` header declares? And can I have a **convenient method** to get the documentation about a certain function?

Comment: Open string.h in a text editor. Man <function> or Google will find documentation.

Comment: @KenWhite You mean in the Linux,we can use `man`,but if we are in windows,how to?

Comment: Google or the documentation for the particular compiler you're using. This site does not help you find them. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @KenWhite "Open string.h in a text editor."  That's great, if you can find the file, but it can be pretty difficult.  These days, more and more compiler installations seem to hide them in pretty obscure locations.  Also, it's more and more common for header files to include other header files which include other header files, making it a nearly impossible wild-goose chase to find the actual declarations of the functions you're interested in.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I can find any file anywhere on my computer, including files that are marked as hidden or system. The question asked (*I have an include statement; how to know what functions are included by it?*) is too broad in scope. Clearly the written documentation would be the preferred location, but the poster doesn't seem to want to put forth the effort to locate it. SO isn't a documentation location service. I mentioned `man`, the compiler/library documentation, and Google.

Comment: on windows use the MSDN

Comment: @KenWhite Don't get me wrong, opening the file is a technique I -- used to -- love to use myself.  But it has been so frustrating and unproductive of late that I tend not to try it any more,  But thanks for reminding me, because I meant to mention `cpp -E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question:

If you're on a Unix or Linux machine, type **`man strcpy`** to get information on the `strcpy` function.

If you're not on a Unix or Linux machine, there are websites.  One I like is die.net: https://linux.die.net/man/3/ .

For the first question, I do not know of a particularly good way to get a definitive list of the functions declared by a particular header file.  There are some decent lists at cppreference.com, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte .

Depending on your compiler and level of expertise, you might want to try invoking `cc -E` on a file that uses the header file(s) you're curious about.  On compilers that support it, the `-E` flag gives you the output after just the preprocessing phase of compilation, so you can see what the `#include` lines expanded to.

Comment: I realize the *Windows subsystem for Linux* can help me.Though I don't sure the *WSL* include all package function..

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following books:

- ["C: A Reference Manual" by Samuel Harbison and Guy Steele](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X)
- ["The    Standard C Library" by P.J. Plauger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099)
- ["The C Programming Language"    by Brian Kernigan and Dennis Ritchie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)

  this last one is the cannonical book on C, written by the dudes who created the language. The answers to the specific questions posed here are contained in the appendix. Very, very highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks very much.